# Real Roots of nth order polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

I have studied that if n = even it may or may not have a real root but for n = odd it atleast have a real root and it is quite evident from the graph of a odd order polynomial as,

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)$$for odd degree is positive if leading coefficient is positive and negative if the leading coefficient is negative.

And
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)$$

for odd degree is negative if leading coefficient is positive and positive if the leading coefficient is negative.

But the trouble is how many real roots exactly the equation have. $$f(x)=0$$

The equation is general $$f(x)=a_0+a_1x+...+a_nx^n$$

Thank you in Advance ...it will be helpful if the this can be explained by taking cases.

Comment: [Sturm's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem)

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I didnot knew the theorem i am reading it now...